# Bitbake yocto image for raspberry pi failed

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to build an image using yocto for raspberry pi3.

1. I use **Ubuntu 20.4** and I made sure that I am on **my-kirkstone** branch as suggested in the latest tutorial from yocto project documentation https://docs.yoctoproject.org/brief-yoctoprojectqs/index.html.
2. In order to build the image for raspberry pi, I've cloned the **meta-rasperrypi, meta-openembedded, openembedded-core and poky layers**. (for all the 3 layers downloaded I've made a checkout on the my-kirkstone branch)
3. I've run the environment script: "**source oe-init-build-env**" and create the build directory
4. I've added the required meta-openembedded layers (**meta-oe, meta-multimedia, meta-python, meta-networking**) to *bblayers.conf*
5. I've specified **MACHINE = "rasberrypi3"** and **INHERIT += "rm_work"** (to save some disk space) in *local.conf*
6. I've used the command "ls recepies-*/images" in meta-raspberrypi folder to check the available images that this layer provides. I've only found rpi-test-image.bb, so I bitbaked it: **bitbake rpi-test-image** and after around 2 hours the result is shown in the picture below.

I've also encountered this problem when trying to build an image for the default machine by following the official tutorial https://docs.yoctoproject.org/brief-yoctoprojectqs/index.html, but I have no idea how to fix this. :(

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m74tX.png)

Comment: I don't use any proxy and do not use the virtual machine to eliminate some other possible errors.